How can I change the text using the new ContentChild signal API?
I'm trying to migrate my Angular component to use the new ContentChild signal API, but I'm encountering some TypeScript issues.
Here's my existing code using the traditional @ContentChild decorator:
// child-component.ts
import { Component, ContentChild, ElementRef, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child-component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild('headerTitle', { static: true }) headerTitleContent!: ElementRef; // Access projected title
  @ContentChild('headerSubtitle', { static: true }) headerSubtitleContent!: ElementRef; // Access projected subtitle
  @ContentChild('navbar') navTitle!: ElementRef; // Access navbar

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.headerTitleContent); // Access title element
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.headerSubtitleContent.nativeElement.textContent = 'Enjoy a customized experience!';
  }
}

I want to achieve the same functionality using the new ContentChild signal API as follows:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { contentChild, effect } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child-component.html',
})
export class ChildComponent {
  private headerTitleContent = contentChild<ElementRef<HTMLAnchorElement>>('headerTitle');
  private headerSubtitleContent = contentChild<ElementRef<HTMLAnchorElement>>('headerSubtitle');
  private navTitle = contentChild<ElementRef<HTMLElement>>('navbar');

  constructor() {
    console.log(this.headerTitleContent); // Access title element
    effect(() => {
      if (this.headerSubtitleContent()) {
        this.headerSubtitleContent().nativeElement.textContent = 'HI this is my name'; // Issue occurs here
      }
    });
  }
}

ISSUE
The left-hand side of an assignment expression may not be an optional property access.


It's because contentChild could be undefined, if the element is not exists in the DOM.
And in typescript you couldn't narrowing a return type of a function.
Two solutions:
I. Chain required after the contentChild, this eliminates undefined from the result type signature. If a required query does not find any results, Angular throws an error.
private headerSubtitleContent = contentChild.required<ElementRef<HTMLAnchorElement>>('headerSubtitle');

II. You can create a variable for the contentChild return value, after that the 'if' statement narrows the type of the value.
 effect(() => {
   let headerSubtitle = this.headerSubtitleContent();
   if (headerSubtitle) {
      headerSubtitle.nativeElement.textContent = 'HI this is my name';
     }
 });

But be aware this feature is just in developer preview. It may change in coming versions.
